# Show Ionic Modal From Inside an Ionic Tab

Tags: ionic-framework

How do I open a modal from inside a tab's view-title, ion-nav-buttons? for example:

```
<ion-view view-title="Users">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-minus-outline" 
            ng-click="openModal()"></button>       
    </ion-nav-buttons>
...
```

I followed [How to open an Ionic Modal from an Ionic Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602797/how-to-open-an-ionic-modal-from-an-ionic-tab) but it creates a tab that when pressed calls openModal(). I want to call openModal from a button on the title bar. I would also like to create only one controller for the modal that can be called from each tab. Is this possible and how would it be done?

Also note, I plan to show a list of objects in the modal. When an object is selected it will change the content of the tabs. Let me know if there might be an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying other than a modal.

Thanks!
Mike

---

**To further clarify**

I’m new to Ionic and obviously I’m missing a key concept. In the below code I don’t know how to call methods that exist in another controller. For example, in the below code I don't know how to call the ModalController's openModal method from the FriendsCtrl's openModal method? Please see the below FriendsCtrl's openModal method.

Here's my code...

**Tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-home" href="#/tab/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

    <!-- Chats Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Friends" icon-off="ion-ios-people-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-people" href="#/tab/friends">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-friends"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

**Tabs-Friends.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Friends">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-minus-outline" ng-click="openModal()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
…
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Modal-template.html**

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Modal</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeModal()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
</ion-modal-view>
```

***Controllers.js***

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('HomePageCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.openInBrowser = function (URL) {
          $window.open(URL, '_system')
    }
})

.controller('FriendsCtrl', function ($scope, $window, TodoList) {
    …

// breakpoint verifies function called in debugger when the button is pressed. 
// However, I don't know how to call the ModalController’s $scope.openModal from here?

$scope.openModal= function () { 
        $scope.modal.show();// to display ionic modal use it 
}

})
.controller('ModalController', function ($scope, $timeout, $state, $ionicModal) {
     //give same file name as your modal html file
     $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal-template.html', {
         scope: $scope
     }).then(function (modal) {
         $scope.modal = modal;
     });

    $scope.openModal= function () { 
        $scope.modal.show();// to display ionic modal use it 
    }
     $scope.modal.show();// to display ionic modal use it
     $scope.closeModal = function () {
         $scope.modal.hide();// to hide ionic modal use it
     }
 });
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved my issue by watching video [AngularJS - Communicating Between Controllers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OALSkJGsRw). In summary I created a shared service that is injected into controllers. Controllers then use that service to broadcasts/handle messages between controllers.

Below is relevant code:

**Controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('FriendsCtrl', function ($scope, $window, TodoList, GroupService) {

    $scope.openModal = function () {
        GroupService.prepForOpenModal();
    };
    …

})

.controller('TabsCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, GroupService) {

    $scope.modal = null;

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal-template.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast_OpenModal', function() {
        $scope.modal.show();
    });

    $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };
});
```

**Services.js**

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('TodoList', function ($ionicPopup) {
    …
})


.factory('GroupService', function ($rootScope) {
    var GroupService = {};
    GroupService.groupName = '';
    GroupService.groupId = '';

    GroupService.prepForOpenModal = function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast_OpenModal');
    };

    return GroupService;
});
```

**Controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('FriendsCtrl', function ($scope, $window, TodoList, GroupService) {
    …

    $scope.openModal = function () {
        GroupService.prepForOpenModal();
    };

})

.controller('TabsCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, GroupService) {

    $scope.modal = null;

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal-template.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast_OpenModal', function() {
        $scope.modal.show();
    });

    $scope.openMyModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.show();
    };

    $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };
});
```

**Tab-friends.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Friends">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-minus-outline" ng-click="openModal()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
        …
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Modal-template.html**

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Modal</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeModal()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Please let me know if there is an easier way.
Thanks for your help Mahesh!

Answer (score 0):

Create new Html page put this html into file.

```
   <ion-modal-view>
   <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
   <h1 class="title">Ionic Modal</h1>
   <div class="buttons">
   <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeModal()">Close</button>
  </div>
 </ion-header-bar> 
 </ion-modal-view>
```

In Controller

```
 .controller('FriendsCtrl', function($scope,$timeout,$state,$ionicModal) {
 //give same file name as your modal html file
 $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/IonicModal.html', {
    scope: $scope
   }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
    });
   $scope.modal.show();// to display ionic modal use it
    $scope.closeModal = function () {
    $scope.modal.hide();// to hide ionic modal use it
    }
  });
```

Comment: What do I call when the button's ng-click fires? 
Also, please clarify where the controller is to be added. Is it placed inside of another controller (i.e. tab controller) or is it added as a new controller?
Thanks!
Mike

Comment: $scope.openModal= function () {
    $scope.modal.show();// to display ionic modal use it
    }

Comment: Hi Mahesh, please see a further explanation/clarification of the issue I'm having in the question above.
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: hello do one thing call this function in both the controller and let me know which one getting call,.... in FriendsCtrl  call this  function $scope.openModal= function () { 
      alert('FriendsCtrl');
}   and in ModalController call this $scope.openModal= function () { 
      alert('ModalController ');
}

Comment: let me know which alert you are getting while pressing button

Comment: The FriendsCtrl alert is being called. It appears that even though the button is above the tabs, it is called from within the controller of the displayed tab. Can I instantiate ModalController and call the ModalController's openModal method from the FriendsCtrl?

Comment: hello mike..Put all your code which you putted into   ModalController's  to FriendsCtrl.Becouse you are getting alert there only.It will work.Try